# React hooks using recharts AreaChart Console Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, recharts, area-chart

I implemented AreaChart from recharts on my app like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AreaChart,
  Area,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  Tooltip,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from 'recharts';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const CustomAreaChart = (props) => {
  const {
    data,
    xDataKey,
    yDataKey,
    areaDataKey,
    options,
  } = props;

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer>
      <AreaChart
        data={data}
        width={options.width}
        height={options.height}
        margin={options.margin}
      >
        <XAxis dataKey={xDataKey} />
        <YAxis dataKey={yDataKey} />
        <Tooltip content={options.renderTooltipContent} />
        <Area
          type={options.areaType}
          dataKey={areaDataKey}
          stroke={options.areaStrokeColor}
          fill={options.areaFillColor}
        />
      </AreaChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

CustomAreaChart.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  areaDataKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  xDataKey: PropTypes.string,
  yDataKey: PropTypes.string,
  options: PropTypes.object,
};

CustomAreaChart.defaultProps = {
  xDataKey: null,
  yDataKey: null,
  options: {
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    margin: {
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    },
    renderTooltipContent: null,
    areaType: 'monotone',
    areaStrokeColor: null,
    areaFillColor: null,
  },
};

export default CustomAreaChart;
```

It works fine now, but I got this warning in console(chrome).

> Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not
>   recommended for use. See
>   "some link" for details.
>
> - Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
> - If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static
>     getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: "some link"
> - Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the
>     UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their
>     new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in
>     your project source folder.
>
> Please update the following components: Animate, Area, AreaChart, Text

I'm using react `16.9.0`.

Do you have any suggestions to remove this warning?

Comment: is recharts using that deprecated lifecycle?

Comment: I can't make sure about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have those warnings from `recharts` packages.

Therefore, if you really want to reduce those annoying warnings, you need to replace the packages with those which never produce warnings.

Let me list down some alternatives below.

http://reactcommunity.org/react-chartjs/index.html

https://react-charts.js.org/examples/area

https://react-google-charts.com/area-chart

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-charts